# Cannot run C programs on MIST architecture

Tags: c, openwrt, mips32

Hi I am trying to run simple C program on my OpenWRT-based router. 
Router works on MIPS architecture:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : Broadcom BCM4704
machine                 : Asus WL500GP V1
processor               : 0
cpu model               : Broadcom BMIPS3300 V0.6
BogoMIPS                : 262.96
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : no
isa                     : mips1 mips2 mips32r1
ASEs implemented        :
shadow register sets    : 1
kscratch registers      : 0
core                    : 0
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

I have been compiling it for various instruction sets (for example mips1, mips2, mips32 or x86_64)

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc-5.3.0.exe -march=mips32 file.c -o file.out
```

And every time when I run it on the router I get the error:

```
./file.out: line 1: syntax error: unexpected word (expecting ")")
```

Example content of file.c file:

```
#include <unistd.h>
 int main()
{
    usleep(333333);
}
```

Have no idea what did I miss, anybody?

Comment: you've probably tried this already but could you `hexdump -C` the binary?

Comment: I tried now
http://wklejto.pl/523324

Comment: It looks like it's trying to execute `file.out` as a shell script. Are you able to run the `file` program on `file.out` and on a binary that you know does run on the router?

Comment: how are you transferring file to the router?

Comment: @user234461 ------
file.out: ELF 32-bit MSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
-------- echo_from_router: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), corrupted section header size

Comment: I see what can be wrong and I generated a new file.out: -------------------  file.out: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, MIPS, MIPS32 rel2 version 1, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped ---------- however right now I cannot run this file "-ash: ./file.out: not found"

Comment: Sounds like the file wasn't copied, or perhaps doesn't have the right permissions?

Comment: I copied it with:--------
sshpass -p 'password' scp ./file.out root@192.168.1.1:/root/file.out
----Permissions -rwxr-xr-x